# Add an array of strings in localStorage without escape characters

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to save an array of strings in localStorage. This is my code:

```
export const saveComment = (state) => {
  try {
    const commentExisting = localStorage.getItem("comment");
    const comment = commentExisting ? commentExisting.split(", ") : [];
    comment.push(state);
    localStorage.setItem("comment", JSON.stringify(comment));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

After adding a couple of values I get a lot of escape characters:

```
["[\"[\\\"Some comment\\\"]\",\"another one\"]","one more comment"]
```

I want it to be like this: `["some comment", "another comment", "one more comment"]`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think localStorage.getItem("comment") is an array. why you trying to split an array ? You should check you variables type.

Comment: @SarperEKİNCİ It's not.  Storage deals in strings only.

Comment: Impirator's got it right.  Also, the way you're splitting would fail if a comment contained a comma.

Comment: on the other hand, you are storing an array. you will use JSON.parse(your array). After that you need to check for you type which is array and string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `JSON.parse` the result from `localStorage.getItem('comment')`.  That will turn it back into an array that you can use directly instead of splitting on commas.

```js
const saveComment = (state) => {
  try {
    const commentExisting = localStorage.getItem("comment");
    const comment = commentExisting ? JSON.parse(commentExisting) : [];
    comment.push(state);
    localStorage.setItem("comment", JSON.stringify(comment));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: It's still adding this: ["["[\"[\\\"adadada\\\"]\",\"CXXzXXX\"]","regfgsfgfggdfg"]", "dfdgdfgdfgdfgdgdfg"]

Answer (score 0):

```
var comment = ["some comment", "another comment", "one more comment"];
localStorage.setItem("comment", JSON.stringify(comment));
var comment = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('comment'));
```

that's it. that's all you need to do.